# Material Icon not rendering when using a [class]

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I use

`<mat-icon class="news-icon-1">language</mat-icon>` I get the icon showing nicely

When I use

```
<mat-icon [class]="'news-icon-'+(i+1)">language</mat-icon>
```

It does not render and I see the word language in differing colours as the class is correctly being set.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you please mark the answer as accepted if the problem is solved. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `[class]`, you override all the existing classes from the element, also the internal ones which are required to display the icon properly.

You can use [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to avoid that:

```
<mat-icon [ngClass]="'news-icon-'+(i+1)'">language</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Legend!. Thank you v.much!

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
<mat-icon class="news-icon-{{i+1}}">language</mat-icon>
```

You have i from ngFor as an index in your template. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dynamic class name, then you should use `[ngClass]` instead of `[class]`.